# string splitting (renaming files)

Tags: dired, filenames

new user here.

I am wondering- can somebody walk me through how to do the following:

In a given directory I have files that look like this

```
fluc_sk2_556.png
even_sk2_922.png
```

I would like, with minimal effort, to move the 3 digits to the front of the filename e.g.

```
556_fluc_sk2_.png
922_even_sk2_.png
```

How to do this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

In dired, type <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-q</kbd> to switch to editable dired mode.

Start `query-replace-regexp` with <kbd>C-M-%</kbd>

Enter `\([^ ]+\)_\([0-9]+\).png` as the search pattern, and `\2_\1_.png` as the replacement.

Type <kbd>y</kbd> to replace a single instance, or <kbd>!</kbd> to replace all instances.

Type <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> to save the changes.